# Where to find free open sourced android custom controls?

Tags: android, controls

I'm looking for some site/library/project with advanced custom Android controls? if you know one, are they free and open sourced?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [commonsguy github repository](https://github.com/commonsguy). You can find several quite interesting android components there, all with source code available under Apache License

Comment: To follow up a bit on mcveat's answer, I have a widget or two in there, but mostly they are other sorts of components (e.g., decorating adapters like `EndlessAdapter`). In general, there is no go-to site for open source Android components like these. The closest is openintents.org, but they have not exactly caught on with Android developers for listing things like this (though their own components are first-rate).

Comment: @CommonsWare IMO sometimes it is hard to tell if one thing is a widget and some other thing is not. Adapters are so close to UI (they can change the way you're operating on list), that I think they may be mentioned along with widgets 'per se'.
BTW, keep up the good work! Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

[android-arsenal.com](http://android-arsenal.com) has a few controls, utilities and scripts; it's a mixed bag but it's the closest thing I've seen to a controls website.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while anyone posted on this thread.

I often refer http://www.androidviews.net/

Tons of free and open sourced custom controls.

You'll love it.

Comment: This website is no longer available.